# Does the Catholic Church teach that it is sinful to vote for a pro-abortion politician?

Tags: catholicism, politics, abortion

Say that a person were to vote for a candidate because they liked their positions on a variety of issues. However, they were also pro-abortion, meaning that they are at odds with the Catholic Church's position on abortion, which teaches that it is a mortal sin. Moreover, the Church teaches that aiding someone in getting an abortion is also a mortal sin.

Does the Catholic Church teach that it is sinful to vote for a politician who is pro-abortion (i.e. supportive of abortion rights)?